# get_queryset in ListAPIView retuns blank list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my app I have two types of users i.e. `company` and `employees`. I am trying to filter the queryset based on this like the following:

```
class ProductListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    # pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.request.user.is_company == 'True':
            user_company = self.request.user.id
            emp = list(Employee.objects.filter(company=user_company).values_list('pk', flat=True))
            emp.append(user_company)
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(owner__in=emp).order_by('-pk')
            return queryset
        elif self.request.user.is_employee == 'True':
            com = Company.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id).pk
            emp = list(Employee.objects.filter(company=com).values_list('pk', flat=True))
            emp.append(com)
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(owner__in=emp).order_by('-pk')
            return queryset
```

I tried the URL with both employee and company credentials but it always return an empty list but when I use the company code independently it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that `is_company` and `is_employee` are boolean fields.

In this case the check should be

```
if self.request.user.is_company is True:
...
elif self.request.user.is_employee is True:
...
```

or simply

```
if self.request.user.is_company:
...
elif self.request.user.is_employee:
...
```

Comment: Isn't `get_queryset` should return `None` (but not empty list) if both `IF`s not match?

Comment: The method, as shared, will return `None` if no condition is met. Normally this would cause an error but not always. In some conditions (i.e. when there's no pagination) if the `None` value can make its way to the serializer, the result will be `[]`